# boostrap left and right margin same as between elements

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, alignment, spacing

I've boostrap elements like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><img...></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><img...></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><img...></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><img...></div>
</div>
```

Visually I've this (_ means space):

```
_IMG__IMG__IMG__IMG_
```

On left and right of each image, I've one space, so between images I've 2 spaces. But on far left and far right, I've only one space. This space changes as it's a responsive design. How to have the same space on far left and far right as there is between images to get this:

```
__IMG__IMG__IMG__IMG__
```

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's `row` has negative margins so that the gutter outside the leftmost and rightmost column is properly spaced and can be full page width if desired.

In your case, you don't want the content full page width so you would override the negative margin on the `row` like this...

```
.row-reset {
    margin-left:0;
    margin-right:0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row row-reset">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><img ..></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><img ..></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><img ..></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"><img ..></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/4ujJLUpx9D